# Printing whole matrix in Theano

Tags: python, theano

I'm debugging my Theano code and printing the values of my tensors as advised [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/debug_faq.html):

```
a_printed = theano.printing.Print("a: ")(a)
```

The issue is that, when `a` is a relatively large matrix, the value is truncated to the first couple of rows and the last couple of rows. However, I would like the whole matrix to be printed. Is this possible?

Comment: Exactly what type of object is a?

Comment: In this particular case, it is a shared variable initialised to a bi-dimensional numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can print the underlying numpy, accessed as `a.get_value()`. Within numpy you can modify printing by

```
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=10000000)
```

where threshold should be bigger than the number of elements expected, and then the whole array will show. See the documentation for [set_printoptions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html). Note that if outputted to a console, this may freeze up because of the possibly very large amount of text.